# morphia - first limit, than filter

Tags: mongodb, morphia

is there any way to write a query in morphia which would limit first and after it perform the filter on the limited result?

example:

I have ten thousands lines in a table.
I want to select first hundred lines.
than filter the limited hundered-lines large query a get the result.

And I dont want to materialize the result of the hundred lines during the process.

thanky you

Comment: Do you have a specific use case or just for performance reasons? If you have an index on the search/sort field (and you really should), then it won't make much difference. And I would be careful with "select first hundred lines" — if you don't sort, there is no guarantee for any order or first

Comment: i want to use it for ajax based downloading of missing record on certain page in a page-enabled table, so I want to set skip() and limit() first, and than on the selected range perform filter..

Comment: If you know the filter in advance (at the time you trigger the Ajax call), why don't you filter, sort, and offset in one go? IMHO it doesn't work the way you try to do it and I don't get the point why you would want to do it like that

Comment: because skip->limit->filter is not the same as filter->skip->limit. Maybe   Im explaining it badly, but if you omit the reason why, is there any way how? :)

Comment: yes, added the answer. just wanted to make sure this is really what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the aggregation framework: `db.collection.aggregate({...})`

There you have the pipeline in which you can call operations in the required order. It supports $match, $sort, $limit, and $offset. And you can even call an operation multiple times.

Here's a quick example, which matches your requirements:

```
db.blog.insert({ timestamp: 4, anonymous: false, rating: 2, views: 10 })
db.blog.insert({ timestamp: 5, anonymous:  true, rating: 2, views:  5 })
db.blog.insert({ timestamp: 3, anonymous:  true, rating: 1, views: 21 })
db.blog.insert({ timestamp: 1, anonymous: false, rating: 3, views: 20 })
db.blog.insert({ timestamp: 2, anonymous: false, rating: 5, views: 25 })

db.blog.aggregate([
  { $sort: { timestamp: 1 } },
  { $limit: 3 },
  { $match: { anonymous: false } },
  { $sort: { views: -1 } }
])
```

Start off with the `$sort` phase on its own and add the other phases to see how it changes the query result

Comment: and how can I do this in Morphia? is there any way to aggregate or run custom command?

Comment: Without details it's hard to guess your query, but take a look at Morphia's test code: https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/10e3abb0c0503be76f2508305e5a2fdfafbf24c7/morphia/src/test/java/org/mongodb/morphia/aggregation/ZipCodeDataSetTest.java#L126

Comment: Im not even sure wheter the aggregate function is the solution of my problem - the aggregate faunction actually something aggregates :) and that is not what I want, I want to create a query which select (by skip and limit) a part of all records and than filter this query. What I want is actually something like subquery .. I hop Im clear enough :)

Comment: While it's called aggregate framework, you are not required to use an aggregate step. ``db.collection.aggregate()`` *is* the only way (I know) for performing a subquery

Comment: that's what Im talking about, to me it seems that you are not allowed to perform any kind of subquery. For example skip(10).limit(5) and from these five records choose only these which's ids are even. You cannot do that with aggregation framework, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you can — I've added an example to my answer. Not sure about even / odd functions, but it is possible in general